# ContentChildren doesn't detect components with *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have a container component :

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let lang of langs">
      <ng-container *ngIf="lang == selectedLang" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

That includes children components :

```
 <app-translated-inputs [languagesAvailable]="languagesAvailable$ | async">
    <ng-template>
      <app-test></app-test>
    </ng-template>
 </app-translated-inputs>
```

I can get a reference of the child component from the parent only if it's visible (*ngIf=true).

```
@ContentChildren(FormAbstract, {descendants: true}) contentChildrenForms: QueryList<FormAbstract> | undefined;
```

How can I achieve to get a reference even if the component is not visible ?

Comment: "even if the component is not visible ?" - that's not how `*ngIf` works. With the condition being falsy, the component isn't hidden, it's simply not there, neither the class instance nor the DOM node. There's no reference to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`.

The main difference is with `[hidden]` it will be loaded into your DOM and will be accessible from the `ContentChildren`.

With `ngIf`, your element is removed from the DOM if the condition is falsy.